# All kinds of problems with Foundation 4 (Zurb) - One page

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

So this is my first time trying to use a responsive framework...also fairly new to building responsive sites in general - but had a lot more luck with just building them from scratch and sizing each element...though Foundation seems like a much better solution if I could just get my head around it!

Work in progress is here: http://client.analog.la/360/

It's behaving 'alright' in my desktop browsers (resizing down to 400) except for a problem with the menu - the issue I'm having is trying to get the menu to drop down below the logo and be properly centered.

On actual mobile and tablet having way more issues...the menu is sitting above and the whole layout or to one side and not dropping down at all. On ipad the whole layout seems to be only about 95% page width with a random margin down the right hand side...on iPhone the whole layout only seems to be about 50% width...which just looks...awful. There's so much discrepancy between how the layout looks on devices vs. how it looks on desktop at the same resolution that I'm a bit baffled...Also, really not sure where I went wrong with the sizing to make it look so wrong on devices!

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Unrelated but: Last time I checked Asia still had a large IE8, 7, 6 users base. http://zurb.com/article/1204/getting-foundation-and-ie8-to-play-nice

Comment: For IE 8 grid support, add respond.js.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for help on this, but there are a number of issues in your codebase, and it's hard to say which ones are causing the behavior you're trying to address. Your very first `div` uses the `columns` class, but it's not nested in a `row`. Elsewhere, you have rows immediately nested in other rows with no apparent benefit, more `columns` nested in other `columns` without an interposing `row`, and nested `rows` that aren't set to collapse. You're also using `spacer.png` in a few places, which almost reduced me to tears.

And your top level headers are in `spans` instead of `h1`. My only guess here is that you were attempting to sidestep Foundation's default styles? Use a class. You need those `h1`s for SEO, semantics, etc.

No insult intended, but you might do well to check out [Treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com) and sharpen your coding skills - could save you a lot of time and frustration in future work.